# Laravel 5.2: where are auth routes declared?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to rearrange the urls used by the auth system. Laravel 5.2. 
I used `artisan make:auth` and now I can't locate where the router is told what to do with `/login` and `/logout`. IMHO, it seems to me a step backwards in the 'ease of use' Laravel strives for that so many commonly overridden features should hav ebecome so obscured in recent revisions.

I'm dividing up the app into admin and public areas and there are to be separate login mechanisms for each: /admin/login is to be handled by the core Laravel system, and /login will be for frontside admin users, auth handled by a different set of classes.

Can someone clue me in please?

Comment: I got it now, you need to build a new controller one for public and one for admin I will post a link to url that helps build what you want.

Comment: in my answer you find the git that cover every thing you need to override default auth

Comment: Yes, from your sugestions I was able to make this work. I will add a how-to example to this question shortly.

Comment: You are welcome to edit my answer I will approve it and you will have my thumb up as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to build 2 systems one for public and one for admin.

Jeffrey Way (Laracast) has made a video explaining every thing you need to build a complete customized login system that is equal to what you get of `artisan make:auth`.

The video link is https://laracasts.com/lessons/email-verification-in-laravel. The video is not free, but Jeffrey has the code available on this git (https://github.com/laracasts/Email-Verification-In-Laravel).

I have used it to build two separate system using the same database.

Note: the link is called email verification in Laravel, but it covers every thing for authentication.

Comment: Thanks maytham, I have an account on laracasts. Good to know which program to look into.

Comment: you are welcome hope that helps and let me know when you reach so far.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the linked content because your answer will be useless if that site goes down.

Comment: @totymedli I will do need some time, to collect all relevant parts.

Answer (score 6):

`php artisan make:auth` adds the following line to your routes file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
}
```

`Route::auth()` is a shortcut to defining the following routes:

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
$this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');

// Registration Routes...
$this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
```

So assuming you ran `auth:make` and haven't touched anything, those will be the routes you can use.

Source: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/the-auth-scaffold-in-laravel-5-2#routeauth

Comment: What I was asking after is a method to override the routes which make:auth has created. You are correct as far as you go, but I need to take it the next step.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change two parameters for the paths.

```
protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard';
```

When a user is successfully authenticated, they will be redirected to the this path.

Second one is the login path. You can customize the failed post-authentication redirect location by defining a loginPath property on the AuthController:

```
protected $loginPath = '/login';
```

Comment: Not quite what I was asking for. I need two different login areas at the same time, not just to change the one.